# Is there a way to preserve setTimeout() and setInterval() timers when dragging a Firefox tab to a new window?

Tags: javascript, firefox, timer, settimeout, setinterval

If I create timers with setTimeout() or setInterval() in Firefox 25.0.1 for Linux, then drag that tab to a new window, the timers stop firing.  This doesn't happen with Chrome on the same system.

Is there a way to prevent these timers from being canceled?  If all of my timers are canceled, is there a way to detect this and restart the timers that doesn't depend on a watchdog timer, which itself would be canceled?

My code follows (also available at http://jsfiddle.net/Kba2S/).  Run the code in a new Firefox tab, then drag the tab to an empty space to create a new window.  The timers will stop.

```
(function() {
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;

    function notice(msg) {
        console.log("Notice: " + msg);
        document.body.appendChild(
            document.createTextNode(msg)
        );
        document.body.appendChild(
            document.createElement('br')
        );
    }

    function foo() {
        notice('Timer ' + x);
        x++;
        setTimeout(foo, 1000);
    }

    foo();

    setInterval(function() {
        notice("Interval " + y);
        y++;
    }, 1500);
})();
```